# Using state and props between React components

Tags: reactjs

This is my project for business card app.
I have a problem with using state and props between components.
Component tree looks like this.

```
Editor <- CardEditForm <- ImageFileInput
```

The url state is in the Editor component. There is a function to update state and give it as props to child components. When I upload an image on ImageFileInput component, url data goes up until the editor component and then using setUrl to url be updated. And then I gave url to CardEditorForm component.

The problem is this, In cardEditorForm, when it comes to using url props, I can't get the updated url. Only gets the initial state. I really need to get an updated url. I also tried to use setTimeout() to get the updated url. But it doesn't work either. What can I do?..

It's my first time to ask a question on stack overflow. Thank you for helping the newb.

Here is the code.

***editor.jsx***

```
const Editor = ({ cards, deleteCard, createOrUpdateCard }) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  const updateUrl = (src) => {
    setUrl(src);
  };
  return (
    <section className={styles.editor}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>Card Maker</h1>
      {Object.keys(cards).map((key) => (
        <CardEditForm
          key={key}
          card={cards[key]}
          onDelete={deleteCard}
          onUpdate={createOrUpdateCard}
          updateUrl={updateUrl}
          url={url}
        />
      ))}
      <CardAddForm onAdd={createOrUpdateCard} updateUrl={updateUrl} url={url} />
    </section>
  );
};
```

***card_edit_form.js*x**

```
const CardEditForm = ({ card, onDelete, onUpdate, updateUrl, url }) => {
  // ...
  const changeUrl = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newCard = {
        ...card,
        fileURL: url,
      };
      onUpdate(newCard);
    }, 4000);
  };

  return (
    <form className={styles.form}>
      // ...
      <div className={styles.fileInput}>
        <ImageFileInput updateCard={changeUrl} updateUrl={updateUrl} />
      </div>
      // ...
    </form>
  );
};

export default CardEditForm;
```

***image_file_input.jsx***

```
const ImageFileInput = ({ updateUrl, updateCard }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const upload = new Upload();
  const onUpload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    upload.uploadImage(image).then((data) => updateUrl(data));
    updateCard(e);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
      <button name="fileURL" onClick={onUpload}>
        image
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your `CardEditForm` component receives the updated `url` prop from your `Editor` component whenever it is updated in the parent. Can you describe how you are checking whether the `url` prop is updated? If you are only getting initial state, then the `url` is never being updated

Comment: Yes you are right. the updated url prop comes whenever it is updated. But when I excecute a `changeURL`function, `fileUrl : url`'s url always got the initial state. On the first click of button, which is in the `ImageFileInput`, it gets an initial state. On second click, it gets an updated state. So I was thinking there is a delay on getting updated URL so I tried setTimeout API. But the result was same :-(

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to create `changeUrl` in `CardEditForm` instead of in `ImageFileInput`? If you want the `url` update to be synchronous, then it should happen in the same callback as `updateURL(data)`.

Comment: Oh wow... it works!! And the code is even simpler! Thank you so much!  You are amazing!!